# Retrieve old value of Intent in onStartCommand of Service

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-service

#### SUMMARY:

I have a little problem about how to retrieve (*or keep*) the `Intent` information in my `onStartCommand` method.

#### SCENE:

My `MainActivity` starts a service with a *String* value ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
intent.putExtra("key", getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
startService(intent);
```

... then my `Service` uses this `Intent` value  — `intent.getStringExtra("key")` — for some things.

#### THE PROBLEM:

But... the problem is which when the user (*or system*) removes the activity from memory and my service is restarting, the `Intent` **will be null**.
(*`START_STICKY`*)

[image: Problem; the user removes the application from memory]

I thought in using `Preferences` for solve this problem, but... I don't like this way.

Anybody knows one well way for solve this problem? Maybe I have a concept problem and I don't know it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`START_STICKY` will not solve your problem because upon restart of your service the system does not redeliver your intent and it would be null in your case.
To get the previous intent you need to return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `onStartCommand` of your Service.

For more information read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

Hope this solves your problem.....

Comment: You're right. `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` works perfectly. Takes a little more time than `START_STICKY` to restart the service, but I do not care.
Thanks @Ayaanp